# Extend JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, extends, jformattedtextfield

I am extending a JFormattedTextField to add a listener. I have this working although it is probably not the best way to do it. Is there not a way to use a single generic constructor?

```
public class TimeLineTextClass extends JFormattedTextField {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private TimelineRecord timeLine;

public TimeLineTextClass (NumberFormat tlformat_,HashMap<Integer,JComponent> fieldList_,int field_,TimelineRecord timeLine_) {
    super(tlformat_);
    timeLine=timeLine_;
    getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // Ignore - Using plain document

        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            timeLine.setObject((String) getClientProperty("type"),getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            timeLine.setObject((String) getClientProperty("type"),getText());
        }

    });
}

public TimeLineTextClass (SimpleDateFormat tlformat_,HashMap<Integer,JComponent> fieldList_,int field_,TimelineRecord timeLine_) {
    super(tlformat_);
    timeLine=timeLine_;
    getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // Ignore - Using plain document

        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            timeLine.setObject((String) getClientProperty("type"),(String) getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            timeLine.setObject((String) getClientProperty("type"),(String) getText());
        }

    });
}

}
```

It seems like there should be a way to use just one constructor with a generic format type as the first argument and for 'super'. TIA.

Comment: Why do you extend from the JFormattedTextField class? You can add the listener after you have create a JFormatterTextField object.

Comment: Yes, I could but there are 2 reasons. The first is because it was suggested I do it that way in another question asked here based on how I wanted to use it. The second reason is that it is an opportunity to learn how extend classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#JFormattedTextField(java.text.Format)) constructors, you can use the type `Format` to catch the `NumberFormat` type and the `SimpleDateFormat` type.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.